# How can i replace two lines in a row of equals characters and put just one with that characters?

Tags: python, replace, text-files, readlines

```
def deletematerial():
    print('Deleting of material ')
    fh_r = open("AQUESTO.txt", "r")
    name = input('Enter the name of de material to eliminate: ').lower()
    print("\n")
    with open("bb.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in fh_r:
            if name not in line.strip("\n"):
                output.write(line)
    fh_r.close()
    os.remove("AQUESTO.txt")
    os.replace('bb.txt', 'AQUESTO.txt')
```

The text file looks like this:

[image]

### example:

```
name     |  priority
====================
gun      |  low
--------------------
granade  |  high
--------------------
explosive|  high
--------------------
```

Everytime I delete something the file finish like this:

[image]

---

```
name     |  priority
====================
gun      |  low
-------------------- <-------this line of separation, I don't want 
--------------------        I only want one of those two, without
explosive|  high            deleting the others
--------------------
```

So I want to replace those two lines of characters for one

Comment: I can not produce your error on the simple files I tested.  You should provide your file example files as text rather than images so I and others can easily reproduce what you are doing i.e. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yeah I try but it was dificult to understand it, so i put the photos

Comment: If the text alone is difficult to understand then you should add the text with the photos.  It's hard to tell from the photos what text you want to change.

Comment: The text doesn't allow to put the thing I want to change, let me see

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

- You only delete lines past the header row

Solution

- We need to advance to the next line after we find a line we want to delete

**Code**

```
import os

def delete_material(filenm):  # PEP 8 function naming convention
    
    print('Deleting of material ')
    name = input('Enter the name of de material to eliminate: ').lower()
    print()

    with  open(filenm, "r") as fh_r, open('temp.txt', "w") as output:
        for line in fh_r:
            if name in line.rstrip():
                  next(fh_r)  # skip next line
            else:
                output.write(line)

    os.replace('temp.txt', filenm) # do not need to delete before calling replace
```

**Ussage Example**

```
delete_material("AQUESTO.txt")
```

Terminal:

```
Deleting of material 
Enter the name of de material to eliminate: gun
```

File test1.txt

```
name     |  priority
====================
gun      |  low
--------------------
granade  |  high
--------------------
explosive|  high
--------------------
```

New Test1.txt

```
name     |  priority
====================
granade  |  high
--------------------
explosive|  high
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, it looks like in this case you are writing an extra blank line to the file when the condition happens in your script.

```
if name not in line.strip("\n"):
    output.write(line)
```

This is saying that when the input doesn’t match a line in your text file, you are just writing a blank line where the condition started. So when you read the text file again it’s showing that extra line you wrote to the file.

Comment: It looks like an extra blank line is being written but we don't see that in OP's code do we (not downvoting just asking)?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Following the logic it was the only thing that I saw wrong that would produce this problem. Sorry still kind of new to SO.

Comment: No problem.  As I mentioned in my comment to OP's post, I don't get this error using their posted code on a data file I generated.  So, we need OP to clarify by providing the data file they're using.

Comment: Oh okay I’m sorry!

Comment: it's more like an aesthetic, when l deleted the line with the word, the file that have the underscore to separate lines just mantain the same, so I only deleting the words with my code. I want to delete the two lines that have underscore and just put one line with underscore(there is not blank line, It's the underscore that make it look that way)